# require or requires? (verb agreement)

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

> Achieving goals like opening a business, buying a home or going on
>   dream vacation, **require** a basic method of savings to make it
>   happen.

My question is is this verb form correct? Or should it be **requires** instead?
What's the grammar topic here? Please explain.

Comment: The subject is the act of achieving.... a singular subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subject of this sentence is "Achieving goals", and it is singular. The examples you mention do not make your subject plural. Therefore, it would be "requires". This is subject-verb agreement but should also fall under the gerund (achieving is a verb that operates as a noun) category.